# Is it possible to wrap text around image as shown below

Tags: html, image, css, text

I need to wrap text around image like this [image: hat Iam looking for]

I have used the following Css tricks

```
img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

p {
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 2em;
}
```

But iam getting results lik this [image: Result I am getting]

Comment: Don't think so. The first content you added looks like an image rather than by html.

Comment: Try this link.  https://codepen.io/nailaahmad/pen/jorKC

Comment: you can find better solutions if the image is in SVG format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shape-outside` property. But I am afraid that it is not supported on all browsers.

See reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/

Browser support: https://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside

```css
.element{
  shape-outside: url(https://png.icons8.com/metro/300/right-footprint.png);
  shape-image-threshold: 0.5;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<img class="element" src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/300/right-footprint.png" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut possit iudicabit usu, ea est detracto intellegat, minim splendide pertinacia te nec. Eu eos elit eripuit bonorum. Eu qui decore indoctum, qui elitr propriae intellegat id. Mei fabulas oporteat postulant eu. Eam at denique vituperata, eu quo ullum oblique, ne prompta iudicabit ius.

Te paulo audire adipisci eum. Has unum errem blandit in, integre dolorem graecis cum ex. Cum at doctus voluptaria voluptatibus. Cibo facilisi abhorreant cu cum. Mei ex zril lucilius. Vix scripserit persequeris ne, cu etiam disputando mea.

Sed ei tollit commune consequat, te alii cibo eleifend mel. Meis bonorum usu eu. Ea graecis necessitatibus ius. Semper utamur usu eu, utinam consectetuer his ei, id decore perpetua per.

Est ea modo dico tota, habeo lobortis suscipiantur te vix, viris altera principes ea eos. Wisi verear ei duo, magna partem vulputate ei mei. Cum ad purto prima legere, erant audire qui at. Nominati constituto repudiandae ut sed, mei cu porro error pericula, ad mollis pertinax principes est. Sed evertitur temporibus philosophia ne, ne zril integre temporibus qui, his option postulant assentior ne. Id mea labore appellantur, has hinc populo cu, at vis elitr everti torquatos.

Hinc purto illum an vis, nam tation sensibus at, reque munere complectitur id sed. Vel everti assentior conceptam te. Vel ut reque dolorum assentior, apeirian liberavisse at nam, vix at regione evertitur temporibus. Blandit persecuti sadipscing no mei.</p>
```

Comment: its working in chrome and Ios safari not sure in firefox any way good answer

Comment: Not working on FF 61, but it seems that will be supported on the next release FF 62